# Calling UIWebViewDelegate method "when I want"

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm using the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` method to call my Objective-C code from JavaScript which works OK. The problem is, this method only gets called when a Web view reloads. I want to be able to send messages "whenever I want". Is that possible?

Specifically I want to use `document.location = "myapp:" + "customerAdded:" + "YES";` as often as I please. My code only gets executed when I draw the map using Google API V3.

Is it possible to reload an "invisible" frame in order to call the delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, works fine for me

```
function invokeObjectiveC() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute(your stuff here);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}
```

Comment: So this method fires the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` ?

Answer (score 0):

`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` should only be called when the web view reloads, that's the purpose of this delegate. You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to call a method that reloads your webview.

Comment: must it reload the whole page in order to call the delegate?

Comment: Yes, you can't load part of a webpage anyway